# Правильно ли: 30 тысяч?

Tags: числительные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, будет ли ошибкой записать число 30 000 вот так: "30 тысяч"? И как вообще корректнее всего писать в тексте подобные числа?
И еще у меня вопрос: если пишешь такое число цифрами, нужно ли делать пробел после десятков или все нули пишутся без пробела?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если писать в тексте, то я бы написала всё словами: тридцать тысяч. Если не формально писать, то я думаю нету большой разницы между "30 тысяч" и "30 000". С разделением между сотнями и тысячами получается красивее и понятнее, когда такие большие числа. Но опять же - если писать в тексте, то правильней писать словами, и тогда нету этой проблемы.